# Need help creating my C++ program

Tags: c++

I am having trouble creating my C++ program. I want it not to play a sound when `'N'` is entered. If I press `'Y'` the sound plays no problem.

I am creating my own program and I want it to not play sound when anything other than `'Y'` is entered. I am creating a console application in Visual Studio 2010.

Right now, the program plays sound even if `'n'` is entered.
Here is the code:

```
// Dial Up Console.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
using namespace std; 

char dialy;

char bonzi;


int playsound(); 


int main()
  {
     cout << "Do you like the handshake sound of dial up?"; 

     cin >> dialy;

     if (dialy=='y')
       {
         cout <<"Here you go! Enjoy! \n"; 
         PlaySound(TEXT("C:\\Users\\Sam\\Dropbox\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\Dial Up Console\\dialup.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC); // I don't want the sound to play if N is entered. 
       }

     if (dialy=='n')             
       {
          cout <<   "Have you heard of BonziBUDDY? \n";
          cin >> bonzi;
       }
     else    
       {
          cout << "Sorry dude! I don't understand! boogey ball! baby!";
       }
     if (bonzi=='y')
       {
          cout << "Good. You were born a long to know that dial up Internet existed. Here is a nice little sound clip for you to enjoy!";
       }
     else if (bonzi=='n')
       {
         cout << "Congratulations! You do not slow Internet and you're not old. Goodbye baby!";
       }
     else 
       {
          cout << "Sorry dude! I don't understand! boogey ball! baby!";  
       }
     system("pause");
     return 0; 
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I have understood, I have changed your code to this

```
int main()
  {
     cout << "Do you like the handshake sound of dial up?"; 
     cin >> dialy;

     if ( dialy == 'y' || dialy == 'Y' )  // checks for capital and small letter
       {                                 // This is where the main problem was. Only the cout statement was in the if block
         cout <<"Here you go! Enjoy! \n";       
         PlaySound(TEXT("C:\\Users\\Sam\\Dropbox\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\Dial Up Console\\dialup.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC); // I don't want the sound to play if N is entered. 
       }

     else if ( dialy == 'n' || dialy == 'N' )   // changed to else if
       {
         cout << "Have you heard of BonziBUDDY? \n";
         cin >> bonzi;

         // I moved some part of your code into this if block

         if ( bonzi == 'y' || bonzi == 'Y' ) 
           {
              cout << "Good. You were born a long to know that dial up Internet existed. Here is a nice little sound clip for you to enjoy!";
           }

         else if ( bonzi == 'n' || bonzi == 'N' )   
           {
             cout << "Congratulations! You do not slow Internet and you're not old. Goodbye baby!";
           }

         else 
           {
             cout << "Sorry dude! I don't understand! boogey ball! baby!";
           }

       }

     else
       {
         cout << "Sorry dude! I don't understand! boogey ball! baby!";
       }

    system("pause");
    return 0; 
  }
```

The problem was that in

```
 if (dialy=='y')

     cout <<"Here you go! Enjoy! \n"; 
 {
  PlaySound(TEXT("C:\\Users\\Sam\\Dropbox\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\Dial Up Console\\dialup.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC); // I don't want the sound to play if N is entered. 
 }
```

only the `cout` is inside the if block, and the `PlaySound()` would be called, irrespective of your input ( see the comments ) .

This should be

```
 if ( dialy == 'y' || dialy == 'Y' )
   {
     cout <<"Here you go! Enjoy! \n"; 
     PlaySound(TEXT("C:\\Users\\Sam\\Dropbox\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\Dial Up Console\\dialup.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC); // I don't want the sound to play if N is entered. 
   }
```

I have also fixed some logical errors in this code.

Note that I added the `|| dialy == 'Y'` in the if statements so that capital letters are also accepted ( I have added similar edits to the other If statements as well ).

Comment: That does work but it still plays the sound even if I press 'N'.

Comment: Plus it doesn't say "Here you go, enjoy!" if you press 'Y' after answering Y to "Do you like the handshake sound of dial up?"

Comment: @Samlaptop , either there's something wrong with your compiler, or you didn't even edit your code because your original code ran sound even if you press 'n' because the `PlaySound()` was outside the if condition. Try running the code I have given you ( I didn't find such problems when I ran it ) .

Comment: All it was that was the problem my side was I had 2 curley braces in my code from copying and pasting it.. It all works good. Thanks for my help. Now does anyone know how to get the sound to play in a release build?

Comment: @Samlaptop , that should be asked as a new question  ( also,  I don't know how to play sound in release build )

Comment: @Samlaptop , also don't forget to mark the correct answer as the accepted answer ( click the tick mark next to the answer to mark it as the accepted one, read this [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Welcome to SO ).

Answer (score 1):

Whether input is 'y' or not, Playsound will execute because of the braces.

It should be

```
if (dialy=='y')
{
         cout <<"Here you go! Enjoy!";
      PlaySound(TEXT("C:\\Users\\Sam\\Dropbox\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\Dial Up Console\\dialup.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC); // I don't want the sound to play if N is entered. 
     }
```

*I only checked for the first `if` condition.